# git clone not work and return 403 http error

Tags: git, github, version-control

i can't clone any repository in my server.

when run

`git clone http://github.com/farshidrezaei/fitpic.git`,

I encounter the following error:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/domains/test/fitpic/.git/
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/farshidrezaei/fitpic.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Why do I encounter the following error? How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you’ll need to complete the steps on this page before you can clone down your repo: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/

Specifically, there’s a section for “Setting Up Git” that I think may be exactly what you need.

One last thing: I think you’ll want to use https instead of http for your github url :)